# GNOME 3.14+ launch new gnome-terminal and set title

Tags: bash, alias, gnome-terminal

To the disappointment of many, tab/window title can't be set anymore with `--title`

I use bash. I have had a few aliases I have used to connect to remote servers with.

```
alias c:prod='gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --profile=Production \
--title="Production Server" -e "ssh <url>" &'
```

I found a workaround for GNOME 3.14+ to set title which works well in the command line once put in `.bashrc`

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$@\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

However, this only seems to be effective if placed and called in the remote server's `.bashrc` i.e. I can only change the title after login.

It has no effect, whatsoever if I attempt to change the title of the new window before connecting:

```
alias c:prod='gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --profile=Production \
-e "bash -c \"source ~/.bashrc;set-title Production;ssh <url>\"" &'
```

Setting window title on the remote feels wrong, when the terminal is running on my box, and I cannot make it work on servers either where my user does not happen to have a home directory to put a `.bashrc` in.

Is there a forest I can't see for the trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Append `set-title` function to `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   function set-title() {
     if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
       ORIG=$PS1
     fi
     TITLE="\[\e]2;$@\a\]"
     PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
   }
   ```
2. Install `expect`, if you don't have it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install expect
   ```
3. Create `ProductionServer.sh` with content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env expect

   spawn bash
   expect -re $ {send -- "set-title \"Production Server\"\rclear\rssh user@1.2.3.4\rclear\r"}
   interact
   exit
   ```
4. Exec `gnome-terminal` with arguments:

   ```
   gnome-terminal --hide-menubar -e ~/ProductionServer.sh
   ```

Maybe that process can be optimized, but problem already solved.